# Serial Port Timeout Issues with Windows 10 and Atmega Chip

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, serial-port, atmega

We are using an old Atmega2560 that uses the classic Atmel 109 Bootloader for self-programming. This code has been compiled with CodeVision AVR.

In order to flash the firmware via a PC we used to run a command line tool based on the Atmel 911 App Note. We connect the Atmega to a computer via a Silicon Labs CP2103 USB to UART bridge. I have the latest VCP driver from Silabs installed.

Under Windows 10 and/or faster machines this CL tool constantly throws timeout errors, therefore I took the code and tried to port it to Windows 10 using the VS 2019 community edition (x86). Before VS, I used the freeware Dev-C++, as it was referenced in the actual app note, but no luck. I also tried to adapt the AVR911 code by integrating the hints in Silicon Labs' App Note 197, mainly all the overlapped stuff. I played around with commtimeouts and buffering flags, but nothing yielded satisfying and reproduceable results.

Still, I get timeout errors, mostly during Read operations but sometimes write operations fail as well.

Randomly, instead of programming the flash, the lock bits get changed, which is really strange and a bit scary. I'm not an expert for Windows apps as I mostly do work on the embedded side, so please forgive me for any weird code snippets :)

```
/* Open the communication channel */
void SerialPort::openChannel()
{
    char comName[] = "COMx";
    COMMTIMEOUTS comTimeouts;
    DCB comState;

    /* Reserve Space for the COM State DCB */
    FillMemory(&comState, sizeof(comState), 0);
    comState.DCBlength = sizeof(comState);

    /* Check if channel already open */
    if( channelOpen )
        throw new ErrorMsg( "Channel already open! Cannot open port twice." );

    /* Generate COM filename and attempt open */
    comName[3] = '0' + (char)portNumber;

    serialHandle = CreateFileA( comName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL );

    /* Print error and return if failed opening port */
    if( serialHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        throw new ErrorMsg( "Error opening COM port!" );

    channelOpen = true;

    /* Purge COM Port as suggested by CP210x AN197 */
    if (!PurgeComm(serialHandle, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR))
        throw new ErrorMsg("Error purging COM port!");

    /* Store old COM port settings */
    if( !GetCommTimeouts( serialHandle, &oldComTimeouts ) )
        throw new ErrorMsg( "Error reading COM port settings!" );

    if (!GetCommState(serialHandle, &oldComState))
        throw new ErrorMsg("Error reading COM port state settings!");

    /* Get another copy of the COM timeout settings, and change them */
    if( !GetCommTimeouts( serialHandle, &comTimeouts ) )
        throw new ErrorMsg( "Error reading new COM port settings!" );

    if (!GetCommState(serialHandle, &comState))
        throw new ErrorMsg("Error reading new COM port state settings!");

    /* Actual Change of Port Settings */

    comTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 5000;
    comTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    comTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 5000;

    comTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 5000;
    comTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

    comState.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    comState.Parity = NOPARITY;
    comState.ByteSize = 8;
    comState.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

    /* Apply new  settings */
    if (!SetCommState(serialHandle, &comState))
        throw new ErrorMsg("Error changing COM port settings!");

    if( !SetCommTimeouts( serialHandle, &comTimeouts ) )
        throw new ErrorMsg( "Error changing COM port settings!" );

    Sleep(60); // Delay suggested in CP210x AN197
}

/* Transmit a single byte */
void SerialPort::sendByte( long data )
{
    bool success = false;
    OVERLAPPED ow = { 0 };
    DWORD written;

    /* Check if channel is open */
    if (!channelOpen)
        throw new ErrorMsg("Channel not open! Cannot send to unopened channel.");

    ow.hEvent = CreateEventA(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (ow.hEvent == NULL)
        throw new ErrorMsg("Error creating Event!");

    if (!WriteFile(serialHandle, &data, 1, &written, &ow))
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            if (WaitForSingleObject(ow.hEvent, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                if (GetOverlappedResult(serialHandle, &ow, &written, FALSE))
                    success = true;
    }
    else
    {
        success = true;
    }

    if (written != 1)
        throw new ErrorMsg("Error writing byte to COM port!");

    CloseHandle(ow.hEvent);

    /* Attempt writing */
    if( success == false )
        throw new ErrorMsg( "Error writing byte to COM port!" );
}

/* Receive a single byte */
long SerialPort::getByte()
{
    time_t startTime;
    startTime = time(NULL); // Read current time in seconds

    OVERLAPPED o = {0};  //Use Overlapped as suggested in AN 197
    DWORD readnum = 0;
    DWORD errorString;
    DWORD data = 0;
    bool success = false;

    /* Check if channel is open */
    if (!channelOpen)
        throw new ErrorMsg("Channel not open! Cannot read from unopened channel.");

    /* Attempt receiving byte until timeout limit exceeded */
    do
    {
        o.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

        if (o.hEvent == NULL)
            throw new ErrorMsg("Error creating Event!");

        if (!ReadFile(serialHandle, &data, 1, &readnum, &o)) //solange nicht fertig
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) //Io still in progress
            {
                if (WaitForSingleObject(o.hEvent, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                    success = true;
            }
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(serialHandle, &o, &readnum, FALSE))
            {
                errorString = GetLastError();


            }

        }
        else
        {
            success = true;
        }

        if (readnum > 0)
            return data & 0xFF;
    }while  (time(NULL) - startTime < timeout);

    /* Timeout */
    throw new ErrorMsg("Timeout during COM-port read operation!");
}
```

I expect the readByte / writeByte functions to correctly transfer or read one byte. When I use the awesome AVROSP II software to flash hex files it works like charm even under Windows 10. Therefore I assume the actual bootloader is fine, but it's an issue in AVR911 vs. Serial Port on Windows.

**Edit**
Thanks for the hint about clarifying the question. My question(s) would be, if there is some way of slowing down the communication in order to make sure no bytes are lost during transfer and receive? I played around with "Sleep" already.
Is there a way to easily edit buffer sizes? My code apparently uses 4096 bytes for ReadFile as opposed to AVROSP II which uses 512 bytes if I interpret procmon data correctly.
Did I use the async / overlapped correctly?

Comment: I understand what your issue is (you're getting timeout errors), but I don't see a question. I'm sure you don't expect someone to set up a Atmega2560 with a Atmel 109 Bootloader, compile it with CodeVision AVR and debug your code, right? So, what is your question?

Comment: Creating and destroying a new event object for every byte you read or write seems heavy-handed - but I doubt that's the cause of your issue.